# RAS in process sdk book

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

thanks for reading my question. I would like to know if is there any book or e-book covering the RAS in process SDK for .NET. Iam creating a new reporting app, i would like to understand more deeply the RAS in process SDK.

Thanks For All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [technical document](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/10b840c0-623f-2b10-03b5-9d1913866b32?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&30953829322545) here you can read.  There's also a [list of samples](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/NET+RAS+SDK+Samples) here.

Comment: Thanks, but this document is very limited... i'm looking for something more substantial

Comment: @DiegoGarciaVieira, is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: I've found, here is the link from the full documentation of RAS SDK for .NET http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27465. Thanks ChristianDev... if you find any book, i'll appreciate